# Auto reloading a Sails.js app on code changes?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Currently is seems that for any code change in a sails.js app you have to manually stop the sails server and run `sails lift` again before you can see the changes.

I was wondering if there is any way when running in development mode to automatically restart the sails server when it detects a code change?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have to use a watcher like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), or something else...

## Example

1. Install *forever* by running:

   `sudo npm install -g forever`
2. Run it:

   `forever -w start app.js`

---

To avoid infinite restart because Sails writes into `.tmp` folder, you can create a `.foreverignore` file into your project directory and put this content inside:

```
**/.tmp/**
**/views/**
**/assets/**
```

See the issue on GitHub:
[Forever restarting because of /.tmp](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/614).

Comment: You might also want to add views to `.foreverignore` as they do not require restarts to see changes immediately. e.g. `**/views/**`

Comment: but unfortunately these will lead to bootstrap code executed again and loss of sessions.

Comment: I used this but I receive the following warning:  --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms. How do I set this variable?

Answer (score 49):

You can use [sails-hook-autoreload](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload)

> Just lift your app as normal, and when you add / change / remove a model or controller file, all controllers and models will be reloaded without having to lower / relift the app.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest/easiest solution. Install the npm and add the sample autoreload.js into the config folder and you are basically done.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Simplest and most native to Sails.

Comment: Im getting `Details:  Error: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fail` thrown by `5/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:221` when I save (using sails 11.3)

Answer (score 45):

For example with `nodemon` to watch api and config directories

`.nodemonignore` contents

```
views/*
.tmp/*
.git/*
```

Run the command after creating .nodemonignore

```
$> nodemon -w api -w config
```

Example for supervisor to ignore 3 directories

```
$> supervisor -i .tmp,.git,views app.js
```

Comment: I like the `nodemon` solution over the `forever` solution given how `nodemon` pipes output back to stdout w/o additional configuration. Makes development workflow easier.

Comment: For the command I just used your `.nodemonignore` example and run `nodemon`.  It works so far.

Comment: For anyone else confused about how running the above launches (the equivalent of) `sails lift`, nodemon knows to use `app.js`.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Sails 0.11, you can install this hook to automatically reload when you change models or controllers (views do not require reloading):

```
npm install sails-hook-autoreload
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-autoreload

Comment: This was already mentioned by Vitalii Maslianok's earlier answer.

Answer (score 9):

install `nodemon` globally or locally.

```
npm install nodemon --save
npm install nodemon -g
```

install `sails` locally in you project as follows

```
npm install sails --save
```

then change `package.json`

from

```
"scripts": {
  "debug": "node debug app.js",
  "start": "node app.js"
},
```

to

```
"scripts": {
   "debug": "node debug app.js",
   "start": "node app.js",
   "dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon --ignore 'tmp/*' app.js && exit 0"
},
```

then

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I have solved it using grunt-watch and grunt-forever with sails@beta tasks. The result is 4 grunt commands:

UPDATE: tasks are available in the current sails version (it's no longer beta :>)

- **start** Starts the server
- **stop** Stops the server
- **restart** Restarts the server
- **startWatch** Starts the server and waits for changes to restart it (using grunt-watch). This is probably your solution, but the other commands are also useful.

Here's the code - I'm using sails@beta, which includes a *tasks* directory, I don't know if this is included in previous versions:

- First of all you have to install forever in your sails directory:

  ```
  npm install grunt-forever --save-dev
  ```
- **tasks/config/forever.js** Configure forever task.

  ```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('forever', {
      server: {
         options: {
            index: 'app.js',
            logDir: 'logs'
         }
      }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-forever');
  };
  ```
- **tasks/config/watch.js (*edit*)** Edit watch task in order to add a new rule

  ```
  // api and assets default rules
  ,
  server: {
      // Server files to watch:
      files: [
          'api/**/*',
          'config/**/*'
      ],

      // Restart server
      tasks: ['forever:server:restart']
  }
  ```
- **tasks/register/watchForever.js** Register your custom tasks (this file can be renamed to whatever you want)

  ```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Starts server
    grunt.registerTask('start', [
      'compileAssets',
      'linkAssetsBuild',
      'clean:build',
      'copy:build',
      'forever:server:start'
    ]);

    // Restarts the server (if necessary) and waits for changes
    grunt.registerTask('startWatch', [
      'restart',
      'watch:server'
    ]);

    // Restarts server
    grunt.registerTask('restart', [
      'forever:server:restart'
    ]);

    // Stops server
    grunt.registerTask('stop', [
      'forever:server:stop'
   ]);
  };
  ```

With this you should be able to use

```
    grunt startWatch
```

and make your server wait for changes to be restarted :>

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 7):

Better you use

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

i am using this, and it will helps to improve my developing speed. no need to edit any files for this one!.

after installation

```
nodemon app.js
```

Comment: Nodemon is good if you want to restart your server for each save. But if you are using webstorm or any ide with auto save it will continuesly restart your server.

Comment: Exactly Mr.Vishnu KR.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this question now, it seems that this is no longer necessary - an application launched with `sails lift` will have a grunt watch task running, and code changes will be visible without a restart.

I didn't realise this was happening at first because there's nothing to indicate what's happening in the console, but it does seem to work without a restart (I'm using Sails 0.11)

Comment: I don't think this is the case, I still have to restart sails after I change any controller

Comment: I also need to restart the app to see my changes.

Comment: This is only true for the files in `/assets` folder https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-lift