# sailsjs live update during serverside editing

Tags: node.js, server-side, live, sails.js

It's annoying to have to restart the sails server when you change something, is there any way to make sailsjs do what meteor does where when you save a serverside file it automatically updates the clientside?

That's a pretty awesome feature, and I love sails but that feature is pretty cool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto reloading a Sails.js app on code changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687818/auto-reloading-a-sails-js-app-on-code-changes)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nodemon is a helpful development tool that watches the files in the directory that it was started in, and if anything changes are detected, your node.js application will automatically restart.

To install **nodemon** (you may need to use sudo)

```
$ npm install -g nodemon
```

Sails.js continually writes to the .tmp folder, and as a result you will find that **nodemon** will continually restart the server. To resolve this issue, simply ignore this folder by creating a **.nodemonignore** file with this single line, noting you can place any other files/folders you wish to ignore on separate lines

```
.tmp/*
```

To run your Sails.js application through **nodemon**

```
$ nodemon app
```

For more information, be sure to check out [nodemon](https://npmjs.org/package/nodemon) on npmjs.org

Comment: I found an npm package called live-reload, which sounds like it does what I want it to do, but I'm not sure. I want the server to push changes to the browser without having to click refresh. Also regardless the nodemon thing is super crazy helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you install sails locally (npm install sails)

Comment: I had to add `.tmp/*` and `.views/*` to my .nodemonignore to make this work in sails v0.11. This is because sails will edit your assets (`<!--SCRIPTS-->`) on build.

Answer (score 0):

If you monitor `nodemon --ignore 'tmp/*' --ext js,ejs .` you will still get the infinite reload problem. Apparently Sails is constantly writing the ejs files.