# Sails and cache?

Tags: sails.js

I am working in a project with sail.js everything is ok but each time I modified something I have to restart "sails lift". Is there not an option where with the server online I could work and see all the changes I did?

As info the problem is more with the js and styles, also I use foundation and when I compile with grunt, I always have to restart the server.

I use this option for raise the sails:

```
 Sails lift --dev --verbose
```

Comment: Are you saving your Javascript and CSS files under the `/assets` directory?  That's the only folder that gets copied by Grunt.

Comment: Yes, there and under linker/

Comment: When you save a `.js` or `.css` file, do you see any output in the console indicating that Grunt processed the file?  Or any errors?

Comment: Could be for that verbose: Rendering view :: home/index (located @ /Users/em/php/swapit/views/home/index)
verbose: Grunt :: Fatal error: EMFILE, readdir '/Users/em/php/swapit/assets/linker/js/'

verbose: Grunt :: Fatal error: EMFILE, readdir '/Users/em/php/swapit/assets/linker/js/'
Fatal error: EMFILE, readdir '/Users/em/php/swapit/assets/linker/js/'

Comment: But if I restart the server I have the "testfile.js"

Comment: EMFILE means you're hitting the open file limit.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux/34645#34645

Comment: @RubénFanjulEstrada Even I am facing this kind of cache issue. I got EMFILE issue in Grunt. Hopes somebody will answer this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto reloading a Sails.js app on code changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687818/auto-reloading-a-sails-js-app-on-code-changes)

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate. While `grunt watch` may watch for changes, it won't restart the server. You'll need to lrun nodemon or some such. Sails, however, runs LESS (why not stylus, I don't know) so you may be able to watch CSS changes and lift sails after compiling less to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in old versions of sails.js you don't. 
But starting v0.11.0+ you have an ability to install autoreload hook that will do exactly what you need.

`npm install --save-dev sails-hook-autoreload`

But there is one note: It wouldn't automatically apply changes into your config files. So if you will change something there, you will have to restart sails manually.

And here is a link to this hook: https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload

Answer (score 0):

Why not use nodemon instead  ?
look into this :  https://nodemon.io/
It does the work for me .
just do a npm install --save nodemon
and instead of sails lift you could use nodemon -w  *x

*x = (whichever folder you want to watch)

for example nodemon -w api -w config will restart the app automatically if there is a change api or config folder