# NodeJS: How to stop a Sails MVC app?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using the NodeJS, Sails MVC framework and it seems super easy to get it up and running. Once I have it set up I just run the lift command it voila there's my hello world running all happy and good:

```
sudo sails lift
```

But when I make some code changes I'm supposed to restart the Sails app. I'm having trouble finding the command to stop and/or restart my Sails app. Please advise.

Comment: Are you running it in a console? Have you tried stopping it with ctrl + c?

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't need `sudo` to lift sails, unless you created your project with `sudo sails new` (which you shouldn't do) or installed local dependencies with `sudo npm install` (which you also shouldn't do).  The only thing you should need `sudo` for is installing Sails globally (`sudo npm install sails -g`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto reloading a Sails.js app on code changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687818/auto-reloading-a-sails-js-app-on-code-changes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're lifting a Sails app in the console (as in your question) you can stop it by pressing **Control + C**, just like any other console app.  To restart, call `sails lift` again.

If you happen to be running a Sails app programmatically (probably for testing), you can stop it by calling the `lower` method on the Sails object:

```
var sails = require('sails');
sails.lift(options, function(err, sails) {
   // Do some stuff with sails, then...
   sails.lower();
});
```

Comment: What if i started it as "sails lift &"?