# How to create a start/stop/restart Linux service for Sails.js

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, service, sails.js

I want to create a **start/stop/restart** service on Linux for **Sails.js**.

Will start Sails (similar to `sails lift` command):

```
sudo service myapp start
```

Will stop Sails:

```
sudo service myapp stop
```

Will restart Sails:

```
sudo service myapp restart
```

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687818/auto-reloading-a-sails-js-app-on-code-changes), but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2):

```
$ npm install -g pm2
```

Then you can use pm2 to start your app with:

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

And then you can manage your process with:

```
$ pm2 stop     id
$ pm2 restart  id
$ pm2 delete   id
```

Comment: it doesn't do the Linux Service itself but this is helpful

Comment: @JJC I know :s but it helps and has other functions like auto restart and you can start multiple copies of the app at the same time and it automatically does the balancing and stuff like that. :)

Comment: you're right. I'm just pointing it now. I also know how to create the service so I'll be using your suggested pm2 for it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need node-linux , configuration guidelines are given on the [github](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-linux) page

Following is an example config you can use

```
 var Service = require('node-linux').Service;

  // Create a new service object
  var svc = new Service({
    name:'sails app',
    description: 'sails application',
    script: '/path/to/app.js'
  });

  // Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
  // process is available as a service.
  svc.on('install',function(){
    svc.start();
  });

  svc.install();
```