# Auto reload client-side files in sails.js/node.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How can I auto reload the client side files such as the .ejs and the javascript files?

I have tried using forever but it seems to only autoreload the models and controllers.I'm looking for a way to auto-reload the client side files.

Comment: What version of sails are you using? The latest version does this by default, you should check your code in /tasks/config/watch.js and make sure your javascript files are in the /assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved it.

auto reload doesn't work on production mode. Only on development

Answer (score 1):

For now, that can not be done. Only models, controllers, views and services files are reloaded. All other can be reloaded only manually.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-autoreload

Anyway I do not see the problem. Only configs and static files are not updated. That is done by Grunt at server startup. And you do not need to do it often, so you can manually restart server.

Comment: my views aren't auto reloading.... im using the command forever -w start app.js to lift my sails app

Comment: Did you install [sails-hook-autoreload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-autoreload)?

Comment: its not working on my /views. I need a solution for the views.

Comment: @MatanGubkin What version of sails are you using? Are you sure you have sails-hook-autoreload installed? Did u run `npm install sails-hook-autoreload` in root dir of project? Check if *.ejs* is turned on in _config/views.js_. I have just checked on Sails.js v0.11  - everything works just fine

Comment: i am using sails 0.11.0. I did run sails-hook-autoreload in my root dir and my view engine is configured to be ejs by default. Controllers, Models and Services are all auto-reloading. I need a way to auto-reload my .ejs views.

Comment: @MatanGubkin Try to remove `-w` key, let Sails do the work. On my installations Sails and Forever conflicting if let Forever to restart server on file updates. Anyway, if start `forever -w`, you must at least add `--watchIgnore .tmp` for Sails projects. So first of all try to simply start `forever start app.js`

Comment: @MatanGubkin I am confused. I checked several times. On my present projects and new created. Everywhere all of files, except configs, are refreshing. So I really can not repeat your problem.

Comment: @MatanGubkin Let's define more accurately. If you are talking about files in **assets** dir, then no, they are not refreshed. They are copied to .tmp dir at server start, so you may [try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687818/auto-reloading-a-sails-js-app-on-code-changes), but I am not sure as that post is for old versions of [tag:sails.js]. So may be you better ask the question on [IRC channel](http://sailsjs.org/#!/support/about-irc)

Comment: My views are not refreshing. I'm not talking about the assets folder just to make it clear. Perhaps it has to do to the fact that I installed sails auth?

Comment: I am totally confused. Really do not know how I can help. The only way I see is to ask question on IRC.

Answer (score 0):

After lost some time trying do this with sails/grunt, i install the livereload browser plugin (http://livereload.com/extensions/) for .html, js and css and the package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-autoreload) for the models and controllers.

It has another way in the link follow:

[Get livereload to work with Sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071363/get-livereload-to-work-with-sails-js/)