# Sails.js run asset pipeline on js file change

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sails.js

I understand when I run `sails lift` that the grunt tasks will run and put my assets in `.tmp/`.  However, if I'm doing local development and want to make changes to some files in `assets/js` and refresh the page in the browser and see the updated code it seems I have to stop the server and re-lift the app.

I know there's a grunt watch task configured, and it seems like that is intended to handle this kind of thing.  My questions are:

- is the watch supposed to handle (for example) .js file changes and deliver the re-compilied/minified/concatenated/whatever'd scripts to `.tmp/` without restarting the app?
- if it is supposed to work like that, what common things should I check to troubleshoot why it's not?

As a side note, I'm running it with forever and simply ended up omitting `**/assets/**` from my .foreverignore file from what was listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18687866/749227).  However, that still has the issue that the whole app is restarting when really I just need the asset pipeline run on change.

Answer (score 0):

I disable Grunt during development and works fine for me.

This is how my .sailsrc looks:

```
"hooks":{

    "grunt":false
},
"paths":{
    "public":"assets"
}
```

Documentation:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt